Reading a pdf in rust
I am trying to read a pdf document using lopdf crate. It is working fine in the rest of the cases but in few files, I am getting these logs as
Unicode mismatch true mu "μ" Ok("µ") [181]
Unicode mismatch true Omega "Ω" Ok("Ω") [8486]
Unicode mismatch true mu "μ" Ok("µ") [181]
Unicode mismatch true mu "μ" Ok("µ") [181]
Unicode mismatch true mu "μ" Ok("µ") [181]
Unicode mismatch true Omega "Ω" Ok("Ω") [8486]
Unicode mismatch true mu "μ" Ok("µ") [181]
Unicode mismatch false Delta "Δ" Ok("∆") [8710]
Unicode mismatch true Omega "Ω" Ok("Ω") [8486]
Unicode mismatch true mu "μ" Ok("µ") [181]
Unicode mismatch true mu "μ" Ok("µ") [181]

Here is how I am trying to read a file
use pdf_extract::{output_doc, ConvertToFmt, OutputDev, OutputError, PlainTextOutput};
let reader = std::io::Cursor::new(buffer);
let doc = lopdf::Document::load_from(reader).unwrap();

let mut output = PagePlainTextOutput::new();
output_doc(&doc, &mut output).unwrap();
println!("Output {:?}", output);

Can anyone tell me is there any better way to read a pdf and possibly not have these logs. They are not blocking but they always come and they  fill up the screen

Please put an example PDF file.

I am using this pdf.
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0920410520310111

Those log messages are coming from pdf_extract. https://github.com/jrmuizel/pdf-extract/blob/8ee752db29cb3063095702ebb852e810b6281063/src/lib.rs#L462

Thanks for clarification. But do you have any idea how can I remove them or have proper encoding for my pdf cause I have been unable to find any..
